# getting correct schema name

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using this query to get the schema name too

```
SELECT sysusers.name AS OwnerName,* FROM sysobjects 
            INNER JOIN sysusers ON sysobjects.uid = sysusers.uid 
            WHERE xtype= 'U'
```

but it is returning me wrong schema name, i know the schema comes from `sys.schema` but not entirely sure how can i get without duplicating the rows

Comment: Stop using those old, deprecated, (and now fake) system tables.

Comment: so what are the new ones, you can share the comments and tell if you have

Comment: You look in the documentation. You make an attempt. If you highlight the word sysobjects and use your browser to search, what comes up? [This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-compatibility-views/sys-sysobjects-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each database, you can use

```
SELECT s.name, o.name 
FROM sys.all_objects AS o
INNER JOIN sys.schemas AS s
ON o.[schema_id] = s.[schema_id]
where o.type = 'u'
```

or you can use

```
SELECT   s.name AS schema_name, o.name
FROM    sys.objects o
INNER JOIN sys.schemas s ON o.schema_id = s.schema_id
where o.type = 'u'
```

or you can use

```
Select schema_Name(schema_id) as [Schema], [name] as [Object]     
From sys.objects o
Where o.type = 'u'
```

Comment: none of the above giving me the schema names which i had created and it is only returning me schema names, i want to get my query joined with the schema query to get the results and that is without duplicates

Comment: What is your SQL Server version?